# Power Electronics Project

Tags: electrical-engineering, design, power-electronics, electronics

Can I use **220-12v,1.5 Amps** Stepdown transformer along with 12V 2A **([KBP200](http://www.eicsemi.com/DataSheet/KBP200_10.pdf))** bridge rectifier to build a charger for 12v, 7.5AH battery or I should use transformer with Higher output, maybe 15V

Comment: What type of battery are you planning charging? Is this a Lead Acid battery. If this is a Lead acid battery then the 15V might work better. What is your peak voltage? What is the voltage drop across the bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need more than a 220V:12V transformer.

Fullwave bridge rectifier output:

$$ V_{DC} = 0.637\ V_{MAX} = 0.9\ V_{RMS}$$

This is the generic formula (textbooks), which gives you 10.8V.  Higher current may cause < 10.8V.  Lower current > 10.8V. As in: the actual voltage depends on the load current.

From [Full Wave Rectifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_6.html).

[image]

The peak voltage of a bridge rectifier has two diode losses (Forward voltage of diode depends on current).

If you do the ideal math:

$$V_{MAX} = V_{RMS} \ \sqrt {2} - 2 V_{F\ diode} = 12V \times \sqrt {2} -  2 \times 0.7V = 15.6V$$

which seems enough to make a 12V charger, but that is peak voltage (top of ripple), while actual voltage depends upon load current.  Essentially if there is no load current, then maximum DC voltage is 15.6V.